# Avoid casting a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I'd like to avoid casting a delegate every time I call MarkAsPermanent method.

Here's my delegate declaration:

```
public delegate void Callback<T, U>(T arg1, U arg2);
```

The method signature I need to call:

```
class MessengerManager {
    static public void MarkAsPermanent(string eventType, Delegate _messageHandler) { ... }
}
```

The way I call it right now:

```
MessengerManager.MarkAsPermanent( "level finished", ( Callback<LevelInfo, GameDataType> ) UpdateData );
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead:

`MessengerManager.MarkAsPermanent( "level finished", UpdateData );`

I'd like to avoid typing `( Callback<LevelInfo, GameDataType> )` everytime.

Comment: What's UpdateData (I'm assuming a method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious answer: write a helper method:

```
public static class LevelMessengerManager
{
    public static void MarkAsPermanent(string eventType,
        Callback<LevelInfo, GameDataType> messageHandler)
    {
        MessengerManager.MarkAsPermanent(eventType, messageHandler);
    }
}
```

You can make it generic if you want. Then just call it as:

```
LevelMessengerManager.MarkAsPermanent("level finished", UpdateData);
```

This is assuming that `MessengerManager`'s declaration *really* has to use the `Delegate` parameter - can you just change that method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
class MessengerManager {
    static public void MarkAsPermanent<T, U>(string eventType,  Callback<T, U> _messageHandler) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought that the compiler could imply the types of T and U based on the method passed, but apparently it can't